# Edit button in Gridview not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to use grid view to display a join of several tables(Empdetail,Department,Country,State,City,Qualification). The main table(Empdetail) has different IDs(eg DeptID) which refer to the primary key ID present in the tables. I want department(and other fields) to appear as dropdown choice while updating the gridview but I am facing issues while populating the drop down list and making the edit button fire. The following is the code.

**.ASPX**

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Database.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Employee Database</title>
    <script src="Themes/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Themes/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Themes/js/npm.js" type="text/jahttp://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-Insert-Select-Edit-Update-and-Delete-in-ASPNet-GridView-control.aspxvascript"></script>
    <script src="Themes/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        //to create a loading effect
        function BlockUI(elementID) {
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_beginRequest(function() {
        $("#" + elementID).block({ message: '<table align = "center"><tr><td>' +
         '<img src="Images/loadingAnim.gif"/></td></tr></table>',
         css: {},
         overlayCSS: {backgroundColor:'#000000',opacity: 0.6, border:'3px solid #63B2EB'
        }
        });
        });
        prm.add_endRequest(function() {
            $("#" + elementID).unblock();
        });
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
     
                BlockUI("dvGrid");
                $.blockUI.defaults.css = {};           
        });
</script>
    <link href="Themes/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Themes/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Themes/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id = "dvGrid">
       <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm">
       </asp:ScriptManager>
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width = "900px" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#b3e6ff" 
                         AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound"
                         HeaderStyle-BackColor = "#0080ff" DataKeyNames="ID"
                         PageSize="10" class="table table-bordered" ShowFooter="true" 
                         onrowediting="EditEmployee" onrowupdating="UpdateEmployee"
                         onrowcancelingedit="CancelEdit" OnRowDeleting="DeleteEmployee"
                         EmptyDataText="No records Selected.">
            <Columns >
                
                <asp:TemplateField >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" 
                                   Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' /><!--Primary key,no update and insert,auto generated-->
                    </ItemTemplate>      
                </asp:TemplateField>
                
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "30px"  HeaderText = "EmpCode">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblEmpCode" runat="server"
                                    Text='<%# Eval("EmpCode")%>'>
                        </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpCode" runat="server"
                                     Text='<%# Eval("EmpCode")%>'>
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpCode" class="form-control" Width = "60px"
                                     MaxLength = "5" runat="server">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "30px"  HeaderText = "Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server"
                                   Text='<%# Eval("EmpName")%>'>
                        </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"
                                     Text='<%# Eval("EmpName")%>'>
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" class="form-control" Width = "60px"
                                     MaxLength = "5" runat="server">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "30px"  HeaderText = "DOJ">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDOJ" runat="server"
                                   Text='<%# Eval("DOJ")%>'>
                        </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOJ" runat="server"
                                     Text='<%# Eval("DOJ")%>'>
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOJ" class="form-control" Width = "100px"
                                     MaxLength = "15" runat="server">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "120px"  HeaderText = "Department">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDepartment" runat="server"
                                   Text='<%# Eval("DeptName")%>'>
                        </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID = "Depddl" runat="server" Width="100px" >
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="txtDepartment" Width = "140px"
                                     MaxLength = "5" runat="server">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "30px"  HeaderText = "Country">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server"
                                   Text='<%# Eval("CoName")%>'>
                        </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" class="form-control" Width = "60px"
                                     MaxLength = "5" runat="server">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "30px"  HeaderText = "State">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblState" runat="server"
                                   Text='<%# Eval("SName")%>'>
                        </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtState" class="form-control" Width = "60px"
                                     MaxLength = "5" runat="server">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "30px"  HeaderText = "City">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server"
                                   Text='<%# Eval("CiName")%>'>
                        </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" class="form-control" Width = "60px"
                                     MaxLength = "5" runat="server">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                
                 <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "30px"  HeaderText = "Qualification">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblQualification" runat="server"
                                   Text='<%# Eval("QName")%>'>
                        </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtQualification" class="form-control" Width = "80px"
                                     MaxLength = "5" runat="server">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemove" runat="server"
                             CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("ID")%>' OnClick = "DeleteEmployee"
                             OnClientClick = "return confirm('Do you want to delete?')"
                             Text = "Delete" >
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add"
                                    class="btn-primary" type="button" OnClick = "AddNewEmployee"/>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField  ShowEditButton="True" />
                
            </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
       </ContentTemplate>
       <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID = "GridView1" />
       </Triggers>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Codebehind(aspx.cs/c#)**

```html
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLDbConnection"].ConnectionString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            this.BindData();
            
          
        }
      
    }

 

    protected void EditEmployee(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindData();
                
    }

    protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && GridView1.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
        {
            //Find the DropDownList in the Row
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            DropDownList Depddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("Depddl");
            string query = "SELECT ID,DeptName FROM Department;";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            Depddl.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
            Depddl.DataTextField = "DeptName";
            Depddl.DataValueField = "ID";
            Depddl.DataBind();
            con.Close();


            //Add Default Item in the DropDownList
            Depddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select"));

            //Select the Department ofEmployee in DropDownList
            string Department = (e.Row.FindControl("lblDepartment") as Label).Text;
            Depddl.Items.FindByValue(Department).Selected = true;
        }
    }
    protected void CancelEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        BindData();
    }
    protected void UpdateEmployee(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        string city = (GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Depddl") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value;
        string ID = ((Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
                        .FindControl("lblID")).Text; 
 
        string EmpCode = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
                            .FindControl("txtEmpCode")).Text;
        string Name = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
                            .FindControl("txtName")).Text;
        string DOJ = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
                            .FindControl("txtDOJ")).Text;
        
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "update Empdetail set EmpName=@EmpName," + "EmpCode=@EmpCode,"+ "DOJ=@DOJ where ID=@ID; " +
                          "select Empdetail.ID, Empdetail.EmpCode, Empdetail.EmpName,Empdetail.DOJ, "+
                          "Department.DeptName, Country.CoName, State.SName, City.CiName, Qualification.QName from "+
                          "Empdetail JOIN Department on Empdetail.DepartmentID=Department.ID JOIN Country on Empdetail.CountryID=Country.ID "+
                          "JOIN State on Empdetail.StateID=State.ID JOIN City on Empdetail.CityID=City.ID "+
                          "JOIN Qualification on Empdetail.QualificationID=Qualification.ID;";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ID; 
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = EmpCode;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOJ", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DOJ;
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void DeleteEmployee(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnkRemove = (LinkButton)sender;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "delete from Empdetail where " +
        "ID=@ID;" +
         "select Empdetail.ID, Empdetail.EmpCode, Empdetail.EmpName,Empdetail.DOJ, Department.DeptName, Country.CoName, State.SName, City.CiName, Qualification.QName from Empdetail JOIN Department on Empdetail.DepartmentID=Department.ID JOIN Country on Empdetail.CountryID=Country.ID JOIN State on Empdetail.StateID=State.ID JOIN City on Empdetail.CityID=City.ID JOIN Qualification on Empdetail.QualificationID=Qualification.ID;";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value
            = lnkRemove.CommandArgument;
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    private void BindData()
    {
        string query = "select Empdetail.ID, Empdetail.EmpCode, Empdetail.EmpName,Empdetail.DOJ,"+ 
                       "Department.ID, Department.DeptName, Country.CoName, State.SName, City.CiName, Qualification.QName from "+ 
                       "Empdetail JOIN Department on Empdetail.DepartmentID=Department.ID JOIN Country on Empdetail.CountryID=Country.ID"+ 
                       " JOIN State on Empdetail.StateID=State.ID JOIN City on Empdetail.CityID=City.ID"+ 
                       " JOIN Qualification on Empdetail.QualificationID=Qualification.ID;";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        
        sda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }

    protected void AddNewEmployee(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ID = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtID")).Text;
        string EmpCode = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEmpCode")).Text;
        string Company = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCompany")).Text;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        /*cmd.CommandText = "insert into Empdetail(EmpCode, CompanyName) " +
        "values(@CustomerID, @ContactName, @CompanyName);" +
        "select CustomerID,ContactName,CompanyName from customers";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CustomerID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Company;*/
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }



}
```

**Note:**- I have searched extensively and on multiple sites so I would really appreciate it if you can tell me the exact issue instead of navigating me to a link. I am new to the concept of Gridview so please critique the code with an open mind. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After commenting several segments of the code I realized that the issue was with the "OnRowDataBound" function. 
Commenting these lines made the update button fire again:-

```html
string Department = (e.Row.FindControl("lblDepartment") as Label).Text;
Depddl.Items.FindByValue(Department).Selected = true;
```

What I could gather from this is that I cannot access an Item template control that way. Commenting the lines made the page run smoothly. However it was at  the cost of losing the functionality of auto-selecting the original data value. I would like to implement this and will post an update as soon as I can achieve this.

Comment: Hi did you achieved selecting the value issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the aspx file I'd drop data sources for each dropdown, SqlDataSource for example.  In the markup you can fully define each DDL and every row uses the same single instance of the datasource.  On editing you need only capture the selected value to update.

So...the DataSource for the Department example...

```
    . . .
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SQLDbConnection %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT ID,DeptName FROM Department"
        EnableCaching="True">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Then in the GridView Template for Department...

```
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID = "Depddl" runat="server" Width="100px" >
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"                               
            DataTextField="DeptName" 
            DataValueField="ID"
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
```

And in the code behind you can optionally select the current value for the DDL from a current value...or not...up to you.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound( object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e )
{
    if ( e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow )
    {
        if ( e.Row.RowState.HasFlag( DataControlRowState.Edit ) )
        {
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem;
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList) e.Row.FindControl( "DropDownList1" );
            ddl.SelectedValue = ((int) drv[ "ID" ]).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of such a control.